# How to display images corresponding to the array list in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

In the code below I initialized the `Images` array with a list of image file names. I want the order of the images to be aligned with the order of the `Names` array. This is what I attempted and I got an error saying

> `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION ( code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0)`
>
> **The console output:**  fatal error: Array index out of range
>   (lldb)

*Code*

```
 class NonameTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    var Names = [" Ferro", "Korean", "HUH?","CatCafe", "UINITY", "FAKESTORE" ,"IRANOUTOFNAMES", "OKAY", "KEEP CODING"]

    var Images = ["cafedeadend.jpg", "homei.jpg", "teakha.jpg", "cafelois1.jpg"," petiteoyster.jpg", "forkeerestaurant.jpg"]

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cellIndentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIndentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)


        //configure cell 

         cell.textLabel?.text = Names[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: Images[indexPath.row])

            return cell
} 


       override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
            return Names.count
        }
```

Comment: As the `Names` array has a higher count than `Images` I guess you are using the former to define the `numberOfRowsInSection` when trying to pick out an element from `Images` at an index outside the array's range it will crash like you describe... If this is _not_ the case could you please show us your `numberOfRowsInSection` method?

Comment: I updated my question with your requested info thanks! @nickfalk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `numberOfRowsInSection` function:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return min(Names.count, Images.count)
}
```

This will assure that you only display image / name for the images that you have *both* a name and an image for.

Answer (score 0):

"Array index out of range" means you're looking for the *n*th item in an array that has fewer than *n* items in it. Either:

- your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method is returning a number larger than either your number of names or your number of images, or
- said method is returning the number of names, which is greater than the number of images.

You should have as many images as you have names, or you should have a way of filling a large range of numbers by repeating selections from a smaller range. (Look into the modulus `%` operator.) And either way, you should tell the table view that you only have as many rows as you have data for them.

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows from your **numberOfRowsInSection** is

Names.count // which is 9

But your Images array contains 6 image names. So you are getting that exception . Keep 6 names in your **name** array or 9 images in  **images** array .

Answer (score 0):

As others have said here, the crash/error is caused when you try to access an index that is out of the range of that array.
Also, as pointed out, you can update the images array so it has the same number of elements as the names' array, or you can avoid accessing elements out of range by applying the solution described by [nickfalk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593153/nickfalk).

Another solution is to provide a default value for the case where the index is out of range:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIndentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIndentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    //configure cell 
    cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]

    if let imageName = (indexPath.row >= images.count ? "placeholderImage.jpg" : images[indexPath.row]) as String? {
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    }

        return cell
}
```

This allows you to display all the names as also provide a fallback image when the image set in the array doesn't exist in your assets or the image name is misspelled.

Note that I changed the name of your `var`'s to start with lower case letter, and I strongly suggest you to do same, following the naming conventions for Swift. See [raywenderlich.com Swift Style Guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#naming) as an example.

I hope this helps with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake in numberOfRowsInSection and it will work definitely

```
return min(Names.count, Images.count)
```